# ng-click is faster than Angular data binding

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wanted to create an own checkbox input control. It should behave just like `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="check" ng-change=”handler()”>` with a different look. I created a custom directive with an isolated scope and instead of `ng-model` I used binding ‘=’ between the directive’s and the controllers’s scope variable and instead of `ng-change` I used binding ‘&’ between the directive’s on-click handler and a controller’s scope method (handler).

#### Controller

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.check = false;
  $scope.messages = [];

  $scope.onCheckChange = function(value) {
    $scope.messages.push('onCheckChange: $scope.check == ' + $scope.check + ' value == ' + value);
  }
}])
```

#### Directive

```
.directive('myCheckbox', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        title:           '@',
        value:           '=',
        onChangeHandler: '&'
    },
    template:
      '<span class="my-checkbox"> ' +
        '<span class="tickbox" ng-click="click()" ng-class="{\'ticked\': value}" title="{{title}}"></span>' +
      '</span>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.click = function() {
        scope.value = ! scope.value;
        scope.onChangeHandler({value: scope.value});
      };
    }
  };
})
```

A working plunk is here http://plnkr.co/edit/oIQbqSzcWUShfdTyDBTl?p=preview.

Things work as I would expect with one exception:

1. User click the checkbox, directive’s `scope.click()` is called which sets `scope.value` to the new checkbox value and sends this new value as a parameter to the controller’s `$scope.onCheckChange()`
2. But in the controller’s method `$scope.onCheckChange()` the `$scope.check` variable **does not** contain the new value, but the previous one, although the parameter ‘value’ is the new value already.
3. After ‘a while’ is even the `$scope.check` variable set to the new value. It seems, that the call from the `on-click()` is somehow ‘faster’ than the Angular data binding. I have thought about scope.$apply but don’t think this is the case - Angular takes care of the binding nicely but it takes time until it bubbles through…

### Questions:

1. Why is this happening? I would like to know it to avoid some nasty surprises, if there are some waiting for me there in the depths of the Angular see. Similar, not answered question:
   [angular directive data binding happens after ng-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860357/angular-directive-data-binding-happens-after-ng-change)
2. Is there a way how to make a new checkbox directive ‘listen’ to native `ng-model`, `ng-change` or `ng-disable`? I would like to approach custom directives the same way as the native ones. Or is it just names of the bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ngModel http://plnkr.co/edit/IPWhZ8?p=preview

Your problem was because your handler was triggered before digest cycle finished updating $scope.check.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was lookin for. You answered both my questions, thank you! It seems that I'll have to look at ngModel as it is my friend while making custom directives...

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know **why** is it happening, but I've found a workaround: to wrap the handler to a `$timeout` block without specific delay. It does not matter if it is the handler of the directive or the handler in the controller, both do the trick. The `$timeout` gives angular time to bubble the binding through.

Anyway, I am still curious why it is like this.